# CodeIgniter: How to check either one of the fields is not empty from the required fields

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, input

Either one of form fields 'room_number', 'pos_token', 'banquet_token' has to be filled in order to continue. That was the requirement and I wrote this code and ended up with conflicts with other parts of the code and it didn't work at all.

```
$room_number = $this->input->post('room_number');
$pos_token = $this->input->post('pos_token');
$banquet_token = $this->input->post('banquet_token');

if(isset ($room_number) && strlen($room_number) && ($pos_token) && strlen($pos_token) && ($banquet_token) && strlen($banquet_token) ) {
    return true;
    }
else {
    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `false` on the condition fails like

```
if(isset ($room_number) && strlen($room_number) && ($pos_token) && strlen($pos_token) && ($banquet_token) && strlen($banquet_token) ) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

and for your condition you need to check with `OR` condition like

```
if( ( isset ($room_number) && strlen($room_number)) || 
    ( isset ($pos_token) && strlen($pos_token)) || 
    ( isset ($banquet_token) && strlen($banquet_token))
  ) {
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to set rules for input fields

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
    //run your code on success here
  }
else
  {
    //run your code on failure here
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I already used CodeIgniter form validation but it then requires all 3 inputs to be filled. But my need was to retrieve either one of 3 mandatory fields. Not all 3 are mandatory at once, but at least one field should be populated. Current code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5842556

Comment: @saucecord you can set rule on condition ,but i mean to say we should maximum use of libraries and pre_build function of Codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `||` OR operator in your if statement. and return `false` if the test fails.

```
$room_number = $this->input->post('room_number');
$pos_token = $this->input->post('pos_token');
$banquet_token = $this->input->post('banquet_token');

 if(!empty($room_number) || !empty($pos_token) || !empty($banquet_token))
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

Comment: @saucecord we don't do like this in codeigniter instead we use formvalidation library of codeigniter.

Comment: @Rajeev Ranjan: Would you mind telling us how to retrieve the result from a code like this in CodeIgniter form validation? Of course, since I have to use both (CI and normal approach in the same method), the code looks fragmented now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$room_number = $this->input->post('room_number');   
$pos_token = $this->input->post('pos_token');
$banquet_token = $this->input->post('banquet_token');

if($room_number=="" || $pos_token=="" || $banquet_token=="")
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```